# Is there any way to undo operation of last command in ubuntu?

Tags: rm

The files located in extension directory got deleted through  execution of rm command in terminal
Please suggest me appropriate solution to undo operation of last rm command

Comment: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk if undo doesn't work, recovering that data is possible, with this utility